# securing messages using Chaffing/Winnowing (python)

Tags: python, communication, data-security

I was wondering about "secure communication without encryption" and stumbled across the R.L. Rivest paper on chaffing/winnowing (and two subsequent posts here at the stack). I am an amateur programmer - and as such should avoid "rolling my own" etc. But I am wondering if I have the right idea:

```
def chopAndTag(data, key):
   salt = hashlib.sha225(str(random.randint(1000000000, 9999999999))).hexdigest()

   data = list(base64.b64encode(zlib.compress(data, 9)))
   mac = list()

   for x in range(0, len(data)): # create hmac of data
      mac.append(hashlib.sha224(str(data[x]) + str(key) + str(salt) + str(x)).hexdigest())

   return salt, mac, data

def chaffing(snum, salt):
   data = random.choice('\'aAbBcCdDeEfFgGhHjJkKlLmMnNoOpPqQrRsStTuUvVwWxXyYzZ.,-_?=! ')
   mac = hashlib.sha224(str(data) + str(salt) + str(snum)).hexdigest()

   return data, mac
```

Quick note on the code: In the final version a crypto-secure random generator would be used (current only used for testing purposes) and sha224HMAC as opposed to straight sha224.

So simply put:
message is entered >> message is broken down into individual characters with MACs using a random salt (publicly shared) and a shared secret >> a random number of random letters with random MACs is mixed in >> message is zipped for compression and sent to the next person.

Now one of the issues with this system is that the message has to be divided in such small parts that the size of the parts would not leak any info. I could be wrong, but by compressing and breaking it down into characters this would be ok?

Sample of the output form the script running above code (and other code not included for sake of brevity):

> SALT: 3f441746966d9e3d269063b5c1b6c787fec25aa865365c60ce580ffd
>   o:b3e7a01578c89fcff5d2eae4bb1d49a740f6ef935815d706d5e94417
>   6:16198f8ee137368cef98f469f97c2ceeca7a1f4a1ec0c01fc83521ec
>   D:eb8532e15487c31efc39b1e381401c9d994a6b591ba00efc8089ced5
>   L:9d3124e8b9b5d5e15398c9413b8034dc9d46bb4b298840fcd54854de
>   ,:1043a4ed6ec2316c4d2b71ad1cdba3d0b2cf13a213fc4ac1e9cabb78
>   K:79d97bfd0646ac10e4fdeddc4d7461ec57c6b7005fcfaf790525bf1f
>   z:c30a80b64fc0cbbbcafee69ebfef67f3932e4db7ed67b03a8c2505b7
>   Q:37a8dae3c23364daf793c607b68a5ab5e1c9901242b96c652afb9482
>   p:b117f08b33519ca6ef74bd52f1c8cfb498ea6133e467e669fe7af7a3
>   [...]

Comment: This question is probably better suited for [crypto.stackexchange.com](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the the [implementation](https://github.com/dlitz/pycrypto/blob/master/lib/Crypto/Protocol/Chaffing.py) in [PyCrypto](https://www.dlitz.net/software/pycrypto/).